# Authentication with passport-ldapauth nodejs module in express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having issues authentication authenticate an user for an ldap server. I'm pasting the important code below. Can anyone tell me what are the missing pieces of this or whether this nodejs module is able to do what I want to do? I've been trying this for two days now and couldn't find a solution.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const ldapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth').Startegy;

var LDAP_OPTS = {
usernameField: 'myAccountUsername',
passwordField: 'myPassword',
server: {
    url: 'ldap://xx.xx.x.xx:389',
    bindDN: 'dn related data',
    bindCredentials: 'adminAccountPassword',
    searchBase: 'dc=xyz,dc=com',
    searchFilter: '(sAmAccountName={{myUserNameForTheAccount}})'
},
};

passport.use(new ldapStrategy(LDAP_OPTS));

app.use(passport.initialize());


module.exports.login = function(req, res, next){


passport.authenticate('ldapauth', function(err, user, info){

    console.log('inside authent '+JSON.stringify(info))

    if(err){
        return next(err);
    }

    if(!user){
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'authentication failed' })
        // res.send({success: false})
        console.log('inside user: '+user)
    } else {
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
        // res.send({success: true})
    }

    console.log('after response..')

})(req, res, next)
```

When I run this I get a  {"message":"Missing credentials"}. I googled for many resources but haven't found a proper one. There are examples using "passport-local" but I couldn't find "passport-ldapauth" example that has authenticating an user with his username & password. Even in this exapmle, we just sent a request to ldap server to check the existence of an user but I don't know how to validate his password after returning the information of that user.

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598664/how-to-auth-windows-ad-users-by-node-js Hope that can help you.

Comment: @Ian - I already fixed this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The github page of **passport-ldapauth** links to  **ldapauth-fork** project. According to the documentation it says that you need to add the property **bindProperty** to your configuration object.

ldapauth-fork says that bindProperty is

```
     /**
     * Property of the LDAP user object to use when binding to verify
     * the password. E.g. name, email. Default: dn
     */
     bindProperty?: string;
```

Hope that can help

Comment: How can it be used? 
bindProperty: username. Like this?